# My 2007 Toyota Corolla dies when I turn on the AC

Tags: toyota, ac, corolla, compressor

My Toyota Corolla dies the moment I switch on the AC. The engine runs fine without the AC engaged, but as soon as I switch on the AC the car dies without even a sign of hesitation. What could be the cause and remedy for this?

Comment: I like this. Of course it could be electrical. I'd like to know if this happens only at idle or at higher RPM as well.

Answer (score 2):

Have someone switch the AC on while you're looking at the compressor's clutch assembly. If the compressor's clutch hub immediately locks (instead of beginning rotation) and the belt slides around the now immobile pulley, then you have a seized AC compressor. AC compressors seize due to a combination of a lack of maintenance and wrong use of the AC system. The temporary remedy to a seized clutch-equipped AC compressor is disconnecting the clutch coil connector so that the compressor can no longer engage. Unless the pulley bearing is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Check your belt to the ac compressor if applicable and check your wiring/power consumption from the battery when you engage the control. Very often overlooked is the cccrm- constant climate control relay module. Responsible for sustaining engine rpm to prevent compressor from switching off and on under load.